# How to install flutter on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, flutter, linux-mint

I'm new to linux mint and I don't know how to install flutter.

> "https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux"

I couldn't understand the things in the link here, I would appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: First of all you should install tools where written in first section. The most important is git, probably others installed before. After that you could try install with 'sudo snap install flutter --classic'

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYB_I6pPHiQ&ab_channel=BackSlashFlutter

Look at videos on how to install flutter in ubuntu based systems. There's nothing specific to linux-mint that you have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain in simple steps :

first install "snapd" in your linux machine using command
Steps to install snapd-

> `sudo mv /etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref ~/Documents/nosnap.backup`

> `sudo apt update`

> `sudo apt install snapd`

Now,Install flutter using snap-

1- `sudo snap install flutter --classic`

flutter will get installed after this (stablle internet connection needed)

To verify your flutter, run following command

> `flutter doctor`

Note: You will need to install Android studio to run flutter on android emulator.

Hope it will work!!

Answer (score 0):

**#Install Flutter manually**

1. Download the following installation bundle to get the latest stable release of the Flutter SDK From :
   [enter link description here](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.3.10-stable.tar.xz)
2. Extract the File > Move to the desire location .
3. then , Just Update The Path Parmanently .Shown in the Snaps Bellow :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for installing Android Studio on Linux

1. Download Android Studio
2. Extract the Installer:

   `tar -xvf android-studio-ide-*.tar.gz`
3. Move the Extracted Files:

   `sudo mv android-studio /opt/`
4. Create a Desktop Launcher (Optional):
   -Create a desktop launcher for easy access:

   `sudo vim /usr/share/applications/android-studio.desktop`

   -Paste the following content into the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]Name=Android Studio 
   Type=Application 
   Exec=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh 
   Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png 
   Categories=Development;
   ```

5.Run Android Studio:
-Open the Applications menu and search for "Android Studio".
-Click on the icon to launch the IDE.